# Does escaping work differently in Python shell? (Compared to code in file)

Tags: python, escaping

In a Python 3.7 shell I get some unexpected results when escaping strings, see examples below. Got the same results in the Python 2.7 shell.

A quick read in the Python docs seems to say that escaping can be done in strings, but doesn't seem to say it can't be used in the shell. (Or I have missed it).

Can someone explain why escaping doesn't seem to work as expected.

**Example one:**

input:
`>>> "I am 6'2\" tall"`

output:
`'I am 6\'2" tall'`

while `>>> print("I am 6'2\" tall")`

returns (what I expected):
`I am 6'2" tall`

(I also wonder how the backslash, in the unexpected result, ends up behind the 6?)

**Another example:**

input:
`>>> "\tI'm tabbed in."`

output:
`"\tI'm tabbed in."`

When inside print() the tab is replaced with a proper tab. (Can't show it, because stackoverflow seems the remove the tab/spaces in front of the line I use inside a code block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your terminal is calling **repr** magic method of the string when you enter it in terminal as is. In the same time when you call `print` over the string it calls `__str__` method on it:

```
s = "I am 6'2\" tall"
s.__repr__() 
'\'I am 6\\\'2" tall\''
s.__str__()
'I am 6\'2" tall'
```

See more on that comparison between those two methods: [**str** vs. **repr**](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/__str__-vs-__repr)
 and that SO [Difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) question.

Good Lack in your future python adventures.

Answer (score 2):

The interactive shell will give you a *representation* of the return value of your last command. It gives you that value using the `repr()` method, which tries to give a *valid source code representation* of the value; i.e. something you could copy and paste into code as is.

`print` on the other hand prints the contents of the string to the console, without regards whether it would be valid source code or not.